# How do I make a custom initializer for a UIViewController subclass in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, initialization

Apologies if this has been asked before, I've searched around a lot and many answers are from earlier Swift betas when things were different. I can't seem to find a definitive answer.

I want to subclass `UIViewController` and have a custom initializer to allow me to set it up in code easily. I'm having trouble doing this in Swift.

I want an `init()` function that I can use to pass a specific `NSURL` I'll then use with the view controller. In my mind it looks something like `init(withImageURL: NSURL)`. If I add that function it then asks me to add the `init(coder: NSCoder)` function.

I believe this is because it's marked in the superclass with the `required` keyword? So I have to do it in the subclass? I add it:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Now what? Is my special initializer considered a `convenience` one? A designated one? Do I call a super initializer? An initializer from the same class?

How do I add my special initializer onto a `UIViewController` subclass?

Comment: Initializers are good for programmatically created viewControllers, but for viewcontrollers created through storyboard [you're out of luck and have to work your way around it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400793/5175709)

Answer (score 218, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
    var imageURL: NSURL?
    
    // this is a convenient way to create this view controller without a imageURL
    convenience init() {
        self.init(imageURL: nil)
    }
    
    init(imageURL: NSURL?) {
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    // if this view controller is loaded from a storyboard, imageURL will be nil
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: can imageURL be a constant instead? ("let imageURL: NSURL?)

Comment: Sure @VanDuTran, we can initiailze a constant in initiailzers.

Comment: You don't need to call any designated initializers in your new default initializer?

Comment: not working xCode 7, the required constructor is failing to initialize the class level property, in my case an Int, not NSURL?

Comment: How to load this kind of viewController ?

Comment: @NikolaLukic - We can creates a new instance of the class by calling `ViewController()`, `ViewController(imageURL: url)`, or loading it from a storyboard.

Comment: Now i get it , i can make manipulation with class instance before i put it in the present view ! Nice...

Comment: I get this error Convenience initializer for 'NamCls' must delegate (with 'self.init') rather than chaining to a superclass initializer (with 'super.init')

Comment: @SujayUN - A convenience initializer can only call another initializer from the same class.

Comment: I had to write mine as     `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }` otherwise with `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` I was getting the error of **Property `self.someProperty` not initialized at `super.init` call**

Comment: @Honey - All stored property must be assigned an initial value before calling `super.init`. In the sample code above, `imageURL` is an optional variable, so it's nil by default.

Comment: Not sure how that's related. If you're doing pure code, then you don't need to populate your properties inside the `init(coder: aDecoder)`. The `fatalError` will suffice

Comment: @Honey - Yes, that's totally fine.

Comment: @others This answer is slightly misleading. I put a different answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58017901/5175709) which addresses the comments I made before.

Answer (score 52):

For those who write UI programmatically

```
class Your_ViewController : UIViewController {
        
    let your_property : String
        
    init(your_property: String) {
        self.your_property = your_property
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
    }
        
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) is not supported")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

This is very similar to the other answers, but with some explanation. The accepted answer is misleading because its property is *optional* and doesn't expose the fact that your `init?(coder: NSCoder)` MUST initialize each and every property and the only solution to that is having a `fatalError()`. Ultimately you could get away by making your properties optionals, but that doesn't truly answer the OP’s question.

```
// Think more of a OnlyNibOrProgrammatic_NOTStoryboardViewController
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let name: String

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // I don't have a nib. It's all through my code.
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    // I have a nib. I'd like to use my nib and also initialze the `name` property
    init(name: String, nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle? ) {
        self.name = name
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    // when you do storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
    // The SYSTEM will never call this!
    // it wants to call the required initializer!

    init?(name: String, coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = "name"
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    // when you do storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
    // The SYSTEM WILL call this!
    // because this is its required initializer!
    // but what are you going to do for your `name` property?!
    // are you just going to do `self.name = "default Name" just to make it compile?!
    // Since you can't do anything then it's just best to leave it as `fatalError()`
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("I WILL NEVER instantiate through storyboard! It's impossible to initialize super.init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) with any other parameter")
    }
}
```

You basically have to ABANDON loading it from storyboard. Why?

Because when you call a viewController `storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController")` then *UIKit* will do its thing and call

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

You can never redirect that call to another init method.

> <sub>Docs on [`instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller):</sub>
>
> Use this method to create a view controller object to present
>   programmatically. Each time you call this method, it creates a new
>   instance of the view controller using the `init(coder:)` method.

Yet for programmatically created viewController or nib created viewControllers you can redirect that call as shown above.

Comment: This isn't strictly true any more, you can "redirect" the call to another init method by using the `instantiateViewController(identifier:creator:)` method that's available in iOS 13+

Comment: How to use here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-storyboards

Answer (score 5):

> Convenience initializers are secondary, supporting initializers for a
>   class. You can define a convenience initializer to call a designated
>   initializer from the same class as the convenience initializer with
>   some of the designated initializer’s parameters set to default values.
>   You can also define a convenience initializer to create an instance of
>   that class for a specific use case or input value type.

They are documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_324).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a custom init for a popover for example you can use the following approach:

Create a custom init that uses the super init with nibName and bundle and after that access the view property to force the load of the view hierarchy.

Then in the viewDidLoad function you can configure the views with the parameters passed in the initialization.

```
import UIKit

struct Player {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

class VC: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var playerName: UILabel!

let player: Player

init(player: Player) {
    self.player = player
    super.init(nibName: "VC", bundle: Bundle.main)
    if let view = view, view.isHidden {}
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configure()
}

func configure() {
    playerName.text = player.name + "\(player.age)"
}
}

func showPlayerVC() {
    let foo = Player(name: "bar", age: 666)
    let vc = VC(player: foo)
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```