# How was UIAlertViewController's initializer implemented?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, uikit, uialertviewcontroller

This is a design question.  I am creating a custom view controller programmatically, but when I try to customize the initializer for it, I must call designated initializer on its superclass.

Either:

```
init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?)
```

or

```
init?(coder: NSCoder)
```

The problem is, one requires a decoder, which I don't intend to provide with my custom initializer, and another which requires a nibName and I don't intend to use a nib.  I'm doing this programmatically.

How was UIAlertViewController implemented so that its initializer can function without taking a nib and an instance of NSCoder?

Comment: please check - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26923378/2955078

Comment: Cool, didn't know I can just set nib as nil and bundle as nil. Thank you!.