# How to inject viewmodel during viewcontroller storyboard initialisation?

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, storyboard, solid-principles

earlier i was initializing viewmodel object inside viewcontroller, but then when i read about SOLID principles (D = dependency invsersion) , we should not expose model view inside viewcontroller. 
so i thought of if i can inject viewmodel inside viewcontroller during initialization (viewcontroller is already designed in storyboard file) then that should work.

something like...
ViewController having custom init like...
func init(with viewModel : ViewModel)

but is it possible ??

Comment: create a viewModel inside the viewDidLoad method of ViewController. like this `viewModel = ViewModel(para : type)` and all models communicate with only viewModel and ViewController communicate with viewModel, viewModel is the interface between the viewController and model class

Answer (score 1):

With storyboards you can't have a clean cut initializer!

When you call a viewController `storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController")` the SYSTEM will do its stuff and call

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

You can never redirect that call to another init method. Yet for programmatically created viewController or nib created viewControllers you can redirect that call as shown above.

---

You can either go with xibs and create your own `init` methods or take a full programmatic approach.

I've discussed this in full [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923003/how-do-i-make-a-custom-initializer-for-a-uiviewcontroller-subclass-in-swift/58017901#58017901)

Comment: umm, is there anything else that you need? :)